# i am trying to use map function in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

VSCode show me this problem notification:
Exception has occurred.

> NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on
> null. Receiver: null Tried calling: map(Closure: (String) =>
> Answer))

this is the main library code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './question.dart';
import 'answer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var questionIndex = 0;
  void answerquestion() {
    setState(() {
      if (questionIndex < 1) {
        questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
      }
    });

    print("answer question!");
  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      {
        "questionText": "where are you from?",
        "answers": ["berlin ", "london", "DC", "new york"]
      },
      {
        "questionText": "what is your favourite color?",
        "answers": [" purple", "red", "yellow ", "blue"]
      }
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("jini question"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Question(
            questions[questionIndex]["questionText"],
          ),
          ...(questions[questionIndex]["answer"] as List<String>).map((answer) {
            return Answer(answerquestion, answer);
          }).toList()
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i am trying to use map function but i got this error message

Comment: ty very much i didnt saw it :D

Answer (score 0):

The value of

```
(questions[questionIndex]["answer"] as List<String>)
```

returns null. So your call will be like `(null).map { }`

Null object doesn't have any method called map. That's why you're getting this error.

In this case, you're getting the value maybe because of the typo error. You're using `"answer"` instead of `"answers"`.

I would recommend you to null check element before using it. There is an [article](https://dart.dev/null-safety) in dart.dev.

> Tip: convert that json into models and configure your views based on
> that model object.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you should try replacing `["answer"]` with `["answers"]`.